# How can I optimize this bottleneck Draw call?

Tags: c#, optimization, xna, draw, xna-4.0

I profiled my application (a game), and I noticed that this function is a (the!) bottleneck. In particular, this function is called a lot due to it's meaning: it draws windows of my game's skyscraper. The game is flowing horizontally so, everytime new skyscraper are generated and windows has to be drawn.

The method is simple: I load just one image of a window and then I use it like a "stencil" to draw every window, while I calculate its position on the skyscraper.

- `position_` is the starting position, based on top-left corner where I want to begin drawing
- `n_horizontal_windows_` and `n_vertical_windows_` is self-explanatory and it is generated in constructor
- `skipped_lights_` is a matrix of `bool` that says if that particular light is on or off (off means don't draw the window)
- `delta_x` is like the padding, the distance between a window and another.
- `w_window` is the width of the window (every window has the same)

  ```
  public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
  {
      Vector2 tmp_pos = position_;
      float default_pos_y = tmp_pos.Y;

      for (int r = 0; r < n_horizontal_windows_; ++r)
      {
          for (int c = 0; c < n_vertical_windows; ++c)
          {
              if (skipped_lights_[r, c])
              {
                  spriteBatch.Draw(
                      window_texture_,
                      tmp_pos,
                      overlay_color_);
              }

              tmp_pos.Y += delta_y_;
          }
          tmp_pos.X += delta_x_ + w_window_;
          tmp_pos.Y = default_pos_y;
      }

  }
  ```

As you can see the position is calculated inside the loop.

Just an example of the result (as you can see I create three layers of skyscrapers):

[image: An example of the result]

How can I optimize this function?

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Instead of closing, please move it to the other forum if here it isn't good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always render each building to a texture and cache it while it's on screen.  That way you only draw the windows once for each building.  you will draw the entire building in one call after it's been cached, saving you from building it piece by piece every frame.  It should prevent a lot of over-draw that you were getting each frame too.  It will have a slight memory cost though.

Comment: The problem is that every building is randomly generated (in width and height) each time I need to draw one!

Comment: I'm assuming the building doesn't change once it's on screen.  You would have a "Building" class that represents each building.  When a new building needs to scroll on screen you create it with your parameters and then render it to a texture that you cache in the Building class.  You can use your existing drawing code to draw this texture.  Now when you go to draw your cityscape you just loop through all your buildings and draw their cached texture instead of rendering it part by part.  When a building scrolls off screen you need to destroy that instance of the building and free up it's cache.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on rendering to a texture in XNA.http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Render_to_texture.php

Comment: Wonderful! I gained 7% speed! Thanks!